# UINavigationController - do not want this to appear first page iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am going to use an UINavigationController to keep track of all the views the user visits. This is all well and good except that I do not want the navigation bar to appear on the first view. Is it possible not to show the navigation bar on the first view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure, you can use `- (void)setNavigationBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` on the navigation controller, when you want to hide it and then use it again to display it.

so if you are on a view controller that is the root for the UINavigationController, you might want to call it in the `viewWillAppear:` method:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```